# Female cats taking over worlds and fighting humans

Tags: story-identification, books

This was a book series I read years ago.

It was about a female warrior cat species traveling through space and taking over worlds and humans trying to fight back. The males were a sub-species only used for mating once every couple of years and the females had to go back to their home planet to mate. Humans were considered property by the cats and had to wear collars. There was a prophecy concerning a cat and a male human, something about trading blood which was forbidden but would ensure the survival of the cat species.
I’m sure it was two series of books, the second set written after the first, but as a prequel.

It’s not *Warrior Cats*.

Comment: This is the reverse of the [Kzin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-Kzin_Wars).

Comment: Hi, Liz. Welcome to Stack Exchange! See [this awesome guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/102999) for some help improving your question.